Why Does Nautilus Trigger open Call for Only Specific File Extensions in My FUSE Filesystem?
I’m implementing a FUSE filesystem in Python using the fuse-python library to mirror a directory on a Linux system. I’ve observed that when navigating into folders using Nautilus, it triggers an open call only files with certain extensions (e.g., .html, .py, .ini). Files with other extensions, such as .txt, .md, .csv, and others, is not triggered with the open call.
Questions:

Why does Nautilus need to trigger the open call for the files?
Why does Nautilus trigger open calls only for certain file extensions (.html, .py, .ini) and not for others?
Is there a known pattern or reason behind this behavior?
How can I handle or configure my FUSE implementation to address this issue or ensure consistent behavior across all file types?


What is the behaviour with xdg-open filename and gio open filename commands?

Yes @KhalidAbuShawarib , the open call is triggered for the file when using xdg-open and gio open, but my concern is not with the open call itself. The issue is with Natilus and other file explorers, which triggers the open calls when entering a folder, and it happens specifically for files with certain extensions.

Hmm, no clue. Maybe it's an extension. Try with nautilus -q and then NAUTILUS_DISABLE_PLUGINS=TRUE nautilus

no, Khalid Abu Shawarib. It is not working
